# Using generic Object type in hbase using Kundera

Tags: java, generics, hadoop, hbase, kundera

I am using kundera to define my data model which will be stored in hbase. There is a class called "Task" which should have a generic type of submission like so:

```
public class Task {
    ...
    Object submission;
}
```

The submission could be of any type since I want to keep it generic.

So my question is:
1. Is the above method a good practice? Will it work?
2. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? If it's the best approach? I don't know. Maybe you could try making the submission a generic type? public class Task<T> { T submission; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a generic type is a good idea. Yes, it should work. However, the type you have provided is *not* generic. Here is an example of a generic type:

```
public class Task<T> {
    T submission;

    // You can now use T as a class (but not with `new` or some other things)
    public T getSubmission() { return submission; }
    public void setSubmission(T new) { submission = new; }
    public Task(T t) { setSubmission(t); }
    // etc.
}
```

Then, you can make a `Task` of a certain type, for example:

```
Task<String> stringTask = new Task<String>("hello");
```

Take a look at the [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more information.